# Windows XP and SAMBA

Tags: centos, windows-xp, samba, file-sharing, centos5

We have a CentOS 5.5 server that is running kernel 2.6.18-194.32.1.el5 and SAMBA version 3.0.33-3.29.el5_6.2.  We have a hidden share created that we use to map network drives to.  This was working fine on our Windows XP SP3 machines and then all of a sudden it quit working.  I have checked a number of things and am at a loss for how to troubleshoot this issue further.  Listed below are snippets from various configs.

**/etc/samba/smb.conf**

```
[global]
client lanman auth = yes
client ntlmv2 auth = yes
dns proxy = no
encrypt passwords = yes
hosts allow = 10.130.155. 127.0.0.1
hosts deny = all
lanman auth = no
load printers = no
log level = 1
max connections = 30
netbios name = SAMBA
ntlm auth = yes
null passwords = no
printcap name = /etc/printcap
printing =
security = user
server string = SAMBA Server
smb ports = 445
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536 SO_KEEPALIVE
workgroup = Workgroup

#============ Share Definitions =======================#
[share$]
comment = Share
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
force group = staff
path= /vcroot
valid users = @staff
writable = yes
```

**iptables rules for SAMBA**

```
#!/bin/sh

IPT="/sbin/iptables"

$IPT -A INPUT -s 10.130.155.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s 10.130.155.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s 10.130.155.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s 10.130.155.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s 10.130.155.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
```

The output from the /var/log/samba/smdb.log file shows the following:

```
[2011/05/24 16:40:04, 0] lib/util_sock.c:read_data(540) read_data: read failure for 4 bytes to client 10.130.155.169. Error = Connection reset by peer
[2011/05/24 16:40:04, 0] lib/util_sock.c:read_data(540) read_data: read failure for 4 bytes to client 10.130.155.169. Error = Connection reset by peer
[2011/05/24 16:40:04, 0] lib/util_sock.c:read_data(540) read_data: read failure for 4 bytes to client 10.130.155.169. Error = Connection reset by peer
[2011/05/24 16:40:04, 1] smbd/service.c:make_connection_snum(1077) machineA (10.130.155.169) connect to service share$ initially as user userA (uid=xxx, gid=xxx) (pid 646)
[2011/05/24 16:40:04, 0] lib/util_sock.c:read_data(540) read_data: read failure for 4 bytes to client 10.130.155.169. Error = Connection reset by peer
[2011/05/24 16:40:04, 1] smbd/service.c:close_cnum(1274) machineA (10.130.155.169) closed connection to service share$
```

I have tried adjusting the "smb ports" setting within the smb.conf file and that did not seem to matter.  I have also tried adjusting the client settings for "Network security: LAN Manager authentication level - Send LM & NTLM responses" and that did not seem to make a difference either.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible Windows Update cause the problem? What has changed on both ends since it last worked?

Comment: There were no Windows updates that were applied or changed.  We did uninstall the Novell client and bind the machine to AD.  However, there is nothing that I can readily see within the Group Policy that would cause problems with this - unless I have missed something.

Answer (score 2):

A stab in the dark: Your Samba server is in a Workgroup group. Your XP client is in an AD domain. This may cause problems. Do you have some entries in Samba logs when the client tries to access the share? Does it ever contact the server? At what stage the negotiations between the client and the server break?

Comment: How would I move the SAMBA server to the domain then?

Comment: This HOWTO http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/domain-member.html should help you.